How to show custom error messages with next-auth@beta latest version


Credentials({
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        let user = null;
        
        if (someLogic) {
          throw new Error("User not found.");
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),



Client page -


const res = await signIn("credentials", {
          email,
          password: pass,
          redirect: false,
        });



How can I show custom error messages to users without reloading sign-in page. I didn't get any errors in older next auth versions.
